# Accent marks (grave marks) do not show in my database SELECT

Tags: php, html, database, utf-8

Hello I have problem with my accent like (é)

here I'm connecting :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=noob', 'noob', '');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from taches ');
    $stmt->execute();
```

here I show my information

```
            <label title="Selectdimanche"> <select title="Selectdimanche" id="Selectdimanche" name="Selectdimanche">

                    <?php

                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo ' <option title="';
                            echo $row['tacName'];
                            echo '">';
                            echo $row['tacId'];
                            echo '</option>'."\n";
                         $task = array();


                        }
                    ?>
</select>
</label>
```

I use notepadd++ and my encode is utf-8 in my header i have

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but when I show my information i have a blackbox  like this how i could show my accents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=noob', 'noob', '', 
    array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=noob', 'noob', '');
```

You're missing the `charset` attribute. You want:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=noob;charset=utf8', 'noob', '');
```